# Laravel (5.2) Token Mismatch on API Requests

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

So I have an interesting issue, as far as I know I am doing things correctly, how ever the token mismatch issue is coming up for API requests.

consider the following:

sendPostData() {
    let params = {
      title:      this.state.post_title,
      content:    this.state.post_content,
      tags:       this.state.tags,
      categories: this.state.categories,
      blog_id:    this.props.blogId,
    };

```
$.ajax({
  url:      this.props.urlToPostTo,
  type:     'POST',
  header:   {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },
  data:     params,
  dataType: 'json'
}).done((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

}

When I `console.log($('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))` I get a token string, so no issue there.

How ever when I post to the URL in question I get:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
```

According to these [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection) I am doing things correctly ... I think.

**Ideas?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send csrf-token value "headers" block instead of "header" block in ajax like below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.props.urlToPostTo,
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    data: params,
    dataType: 'json'
}).done((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken but I think it should be *header**s*** in your AJAX request, not *header*.